# Does something form the basis "of" or the basis "for" something else?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, of-for

I am writing some technical documentation and I'm wondering whether *of* or *for* is the best word to use in the following sentence:

> The framework and architecture will form the basis {of|for} our web applications.

This is a fairly specific example. Is there a general rule for this? Or is it more of a case-by-case decision?

Comment: 'The basis of ...' is referring the static _structure_ as or when it is built. 'The basis for ...' is more strongly connoting the initial building block of the building _process_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both.

*Forming the basis **of*** means it is essentially the sole basis.

OTOH,

*Forming the basis **for*** could mean it is one of the factors forming the basis.

*basis of*:

> Agriculture is the main occupation, with tobacco and cotton crops forming the **basis of** much local industry.

*basis for*:

> The company continued to prosper, forming the **basis for** much of the commercial activity of colonial Canada.

[emphasis mine]

Regardless, it seems there's a tendency these days to prefer *for* over *of*, especially in AmE.

English:
[image]

American English:
[image]

[eCFR](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/37/11.34):

> A complaint shall be filed within one year after the date on which the (...) receives a grievance **forming the basis of** the complaint. No complaint shall be filed more than ten years after the date on which the misconduct **forming the basis for** the proceeding occurred. [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 1):

I tell my students that the choice of preposition depends on whether the following noun represents the subject or the object of the verb.

**Based on** your research, we have made the following decision.

We made a decision *on the basis of* your research. (introducing the 'subject')

Your research was *the basis for* our decision. (introducing the 'object')

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are both grammatically correct, so it's a matter of personal choice.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=basis%20of%2C%20basis%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbasis%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasis%20for%3B%2Cc0) indicates that, as of 2000, **basis of** was used roughly 65% of the time, while **basis for** was used 35% of the time.

(It doesn't matter, but, mirroring that statistic, **basis of** sounds more natural to me.)